# How to extract only one element per tag with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, lxml, parsel

I am trying to extract text from the page tag `<dd></dd>` with this command in srapy shell:

```
[w.strip() for w in response.xpath('//ul[@class="attribute-list"]/li/dl/dd/text()').extract()]
```

The dd tag looks like this:

```
<dd> Edelstahl <br>gebürstet (silberfarben) </dd>
```

scrapy returns:

```
'Edelstahl', 'gebürstet (silberfarben)', more dd elements...
```

Now it is important that I get either only the first element "Edelstahl" or both compined "Edelstahl gebürstet (silberfarben)", but in any case not two elements from one dd tag. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
[w.xpath('string()').extract_first().strip() for w in response.xpath('//ul[@class="attribute-list"]/li/dl/dd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tags in your `dd`, better to use something like:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
print [remove_tags(w).strip() for w in response.xpath('//ul[@class="attribute-list"]/li/dl/dd').extract()]
```

It will give you clear text for each `dd` element.

Comment: That works, thank you. However it seems there is another similar issue. In some cases it looks like this: <dd><a href="..">txt</a></dd> which then gets removed. I would also need this "txt" as output. Or at least return an empty element. I am pulling this as key togehter with <dt> as value into a key:value store and the counting is then wrong as this one is left out.

Comment: It is very strange. Checked in console: `>>> from w3lib.html import remove_tags >>> txt = '<dd><a href="..">txt</a></dd>' >>> remove_tags(txt)` gives `txt`. Double check your logics.